# recursion - print uniq subgroups

Tags: recursion, data-structures

my code :

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void printArr(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}

void tr8Helper(int* arr, int n, int index, int b, int* used)
{
    if (index == n )
    {

        printArr(arr, n);

    }
    else {

        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {

            arr[index] = i;
            tr8Helper(arr, n, index + 1, b, used);
        }


    }

}


void tr8(int num, int b)
{
    int* myArray = (int*)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    int* used = (int*)malloc(b * sizeof(int));
    tr8Helper(myArray, num, 0, b, used);
}

int main() {
    tr8(3, 3);
}
```

this is my code so far and this is what my recursion prints for b= 2, n = 3:
[the output for this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XEw5.png)
 the thing that I'm getting trouble with is how to use the "used" array so the output will be for example b= 3 n = 3
[the requested output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JicFx.png)
I'm having a hard time how to think about this problem, how to think about it from above.
how to tell my recusrion, I have used this number, don't use it again. or just maybe skip this row when the print is happing.
please share with me your thoughts and ideas and maybe some tips on how to you handle with this kind of questions

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a link to an image.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your input and expected output, I believe when you say "unique subgroups" you are referring to [*k*-permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n). If that is the case, then you simply need to employ the *used* array (which in your code is passed around, but not actually employed). I added three new lines in `tr8Helper`; nothing else needs to be changed.

```c
void tr8Helper(int* arr, int n, int index, int b, int* used) {
  if (index == n) {
    printArr(arr, n);
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
      if (!used[i]) {     // (1) do not use i unless it is available
        used[i] = 1;      // (2) mark i as used so we don't use it twice
        arr[index] = i;
        tr8Helper(arr, n, index + 1, b, used);
        used[i] = 0;      // (3) mark i as available so future k-perms can use it
      }
    }
  }
}
```